# C++ value initialize items of a custom container

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, value-initialization

Lets take custom `vector` implementation as an example:

```
template<typename Object>
class myVector {
public:
    explicit myVector(int size = 0) :
        _size{ size },
        _capasity{ size + SPARE_CAPACITY }
    {
        _buff = new Object[_capasity];
        if (_size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
                //_buff[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

// more code

private:
    Object * _buff = nullptr;
    int _size;
    int _capasity;
};
```

So my question is, how to make `myVector` be value-initialized in case I'll initialize it as:

```
int main() {
    myVector<int> v02(5);                   
}
```

Here, it contains 5 `int` values, so I need it to be all zeros; same with other types. I commented out `_buff[i] = 0;` as it's specific to `int`. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    _buff[i] = Object{};
```

---

Alternatively, you could get rid of the loop and add a pair of `{}` (or `()`) here:

```
_buff = new Object[_capasity]{};
//                           ^^
```

But this option would value-initialize all `_capasity` objects, rather than the first `_size` ones, as noted by [@bipll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967746/c-value-initialize-items-of-a-custom-container/53967940?noredirect=1#comment94773447_53967940).

---

Also, note that if you want to mimic the behavior of `std::vector`, you need to allocate raw storate (probably `std::aligned_storage`) and call constructors (via placement-new) and destructors manually.

If `Object` is a class type, `_buff = new Object[_capasity];` calls default constructors for all `_capasity` objects, rather than for the first `_size` objects as `std::vector` does.

Comment: That runs `_capasity` initializations, so to create a vector of zero elements you run `_capasity` constructors.

Comment: @bipll True, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when calling

```
        _buff = new Object[_capasity];
```

(btw, why have you moved this initialization out of init-list, into constructor body?) you already have default-initialized `_capasity` objects. Default initialization has the following effects here: while elements of scalar type would remain uninitialized (and reading from them UB), for class types you have already called `_capasity` constructors.

To avoid unnecessary constructions you have the following possible options, among others:

1. Use [std::aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) to allocate non-initialized memory:

   ```
   explicit myVector(std::size_t size = 0) :
       size_{ size }
       , capacity_{ size + SPARE_CAPACITY }
       , buff_{std::aligned_alloc(alignof(Object), _capacity)}
   {
       if(!buff_) throw std::bad_alloc();
       if(size) new (buff_) Object[size]{}; // empty braces answer your original query
   }
   ```

   Remember that again `buff_` should be `aligned_alloc`ed when vector grows (can be `std::realloc()`ed for trivial types), and in destructor it should be `std::free()`d — and prior to that `size_` objects inside it should be destructed (with an explicit call to `~Object()`).
2. Change `buff_`'s type to something more trivial yet properly aligned:

   ```
       using Storage = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Object), alignof(Object)>;
       Storage *buff_;
       Object *data_ = nullptr;
   public:
       explicit myVector(std::size_t size = 0) :
           size_{ size }
           , capacity_{ size + SPARE_CAPACITY }
           , buff_{new Storage(_capacity)}
       {
           if(size) data_ = new (buff_) Object[size]{};
       }
   ```

   Again, in destructor, objects should be manually destroyed, but this time `buff_` can be simply `delete[]`d afterwards.